# Организация шаблонов (Twig) и Ajax с MVC в придачу

Tags: ajax, twig, mvc

Начал прикручивать к сайту Ajax и наткнулся на интересную вещь:
В шаблонах, которые можно отдавать в ответ на Ajax-запросы есть родительский шаблон.

Поэтому у меня появилось несколько вариантов как организовать Ajax на сайте.

Вариант 1: забить на готовые шаблоны, отдавать json массивы и формировать заново участки страниц.

Вариант 2: Заставить Twig игнорировать родителя и формировать участки отдельно.

Вариант 3: организовать HMVC таким образом, что внутренние блоки шаблона будут формироваться отдельно и запрашиваться через http.

Какой вариант наиболее правильный?

Выбрал вариант:

```
{% extends request.ajax ? "ajax_base.twig" : "base.twig" %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый легкий и часто используемый вариант это 2. Определение можно к примеру делать по передаваемому параметру.

Но более правильный это конечно первый, так как тут и скорость повысится так как рендер будет делаться на стороне клиента и меньше будет ходить трафика.

Answer (score 1):

Лично я делаю так(не говорю что это самый лучший вариант):

```
Контроллер проверяет тип запроса, если аякс, то передает привет к отдельному контроллеру, предназначенный обработки для аякса, и дальше выходит. А в свою очередь аякс контроллер(это аякс диспетчер, скажем так) решает какому контроллеру отправить. И там, генерируется блок,страница. Мне кажется, 1-м способом просто за*б*тесь рисовать html тэги(IMHO, js не предназначен для этого)
```

Comment: @Vfvtnjd

> Мне кажется, 1-м способом просто за*б*тесь рисовать html тэги(IMHO, js не предназначен для этого)

Да, это была очень болезненная часть ajax'изации сайтов, но сейчас есть [вполне рабочие шаблонизаторы](http://handlebarsjs.com/) на js.

Comment: тот же тред что и про серверный JS.

Comment: Сначала я тоже думал использовать отдельный аякс контроллер, но сейчас, мне кажется, что использование обычных намного проще и интереснее.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как работает TWIG, но первый вариант уходить сразу, в текущее время он подходить лишь для реализации приложений для обучения(Передавайте привет IE, некоторым мобильным бразуерам и поисковым ботам соответственно).
    Вариант 2, сейчас на своих сайтах(у меня там нет шаблонизаторов) я использую следующий способ:
    У меня есть "главный" шаблон в серединке шаблона у меня "дырочка" аля, <?=$content ?>
    При загрузке странички я отлавливаю: это ajax запрос или обычный, далее view у меня генерируют или полностью страницу или отдает только $content

Соответственно мой сайт сохраняет юзабилити даже при отключенном JS.

Собственно потыкаться: http://protection.avenger-web.ru/

**UPD** специально для пользователя [[@Fike](/users/16095/fike)](/users/16095/fike) и его команды!
Прежде чем комментировать вопрос, наберитесь достоверной информация о теме спора, я вам, подскажу, конкретно сейчас мы обсуждаем AJAX навигацию и наиболее рациональный способ ее реализации. На что вы мне приводите в пример твитер, который использует xmlhttpreques только для подгрузки некоторых динамических частей, какой то форум, который вообще не работает без JS и какую библиотеку не каким местом не относящуюся к AJAX вводя ТС в ступор. В данный момент мной лично написано 3 сайта полностью работающих на AJAX от ссылок до форм, которые отлично работают как в браузерах без JS, так и в старых версиях браузеров. Что вы мне пытаетесь доказать? Если у вас есть какое то иное решение задачи, постите его в ОТВЕТЫ, а ТС сам решить что на его взгляд лучше.

Comment: а по поводу 3го варианта ничего не скажете?

Comment: Категорически нет, это лишняя нагрузка, лишний трафик.

Comment: это основано на исследованиях? или личное мнение?

Comment: Ну я так понял, что 3 способом, вы имеет ввиду. Получить верх страницы аяксом, получить низ, серединку. Если да, то это лишнии запросы, лишний процесс(хотя он и будет keepalive), получение результата из вашего HMVC

Comment: > Не знаю как работает TWIG, но первый вариант уходить сразу, в текущее время он подходить лишь для реализации приложений для обучения

да что вы говорите

Comment: Ну покажите мне подобный сайт хотябы с сотней посетителей. Когда я писал сайт на Аяксе я пересмотрел не один десяток вариантов

Comment: ответ в стиле "вы все делаете неправильно" без каких-либо аргументов. зато с рекламой какого-то непонятного нечто.

Comment: @avengerweb [Форумную платформу нового поколения](https://meta.discourse.org/) не хотите? [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/)? [Twitter](https://twitter.com/)?

> Когда я писал сайт на Аяксе я пересмотрел не один десяток вариантов

ну все, авторитет

Comment: @Fike, а разве твитер использует AJAX для навигация, по моему у них только подгружаются новости, комментарии. По поводу остального, как я уже и говорил, передавайте привет IE и поисковым ботам. Для них вам придется или отдельно генерировать странички или забить. Второй же способ прост до посинения, отказоустойчив и не требует дополнительного рукоблудства, а это всегда будет приоритетом

Comment: > а разве твитер использует AJAX для навигация

не на сто процентов, но подсекции внутри настроек, notifications/home - аяксом.

> передавайте привет IE и поисковым ботам.

передаю привет прошлому веку

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/
http://help.yandex.com/webmaster/robot-workings/ajax-indexing.xml

> а это всегда будет приоритетом

Приоритетом всегда будет UX. Я не особо плаваю в js, но не удивлюсь, если есть серверные и клиентские шаблонизаторы с абсолюбтно идентичным синтаксисом, с которыми не приходится заниматься двойной игрой вообще.

Comment: avengerweb, нет, если бы я имел ввиду аяксом - я бы так и написал.

я проверяю скорость запросов, пока что вижу небольшое проседание в 3м варианте по сравнению со 2м, однако с 3м вариантом у меня сейчас техническая сложность, которую я устраняю

Comment: 2 @avengerweb , мне кажется, что вы здесь чуть неправильно поняли суть проблемы. ТС гласит, `как генерировать страницы(или часть страницы)`. 

Конечно, у каждого свои + и - насчет серверного(php,TWIG,etc) и клиентской генераций ХТМЛ(js,jQuery,ExtJS) тэгов. 

А вы предлагаете AJAX навигацию с помощью function loader() 
(подозреваю, что вы здесь путаете **аякс генерацию** страницы и **аякс навигацию**). 

Причем здесь старые, новые браузеры с отключенными JS (это уже проблема аякс навигаций) ?

Comment: @Fike, вы правы, есть, например, [swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/) (twig клон), для ноды, который можно использовать и на сервере и на клиенте, причем одни и те же шаблоны. крайне удобная штука.